# how to add blockchain extension in ibm IoT

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, blockchain, watson-iot

I am facing problem while adding blockchain extension to IoT service.That extension is not opend at all. Anyone can help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain is not enabled by default, it requires authorization.  You need to fill in the Kick-start your blockchain project form and then the blockchain team will get in touch: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/reference/extensions/index.html#blockchain

Comment: I will check with blockchain team about status.

Comment: Thank you. If I get more help regarding that issue it's more thankful.

Comment: May I know the status of blockchain team.

Comment: they did not find a form with your name.  Was it submitted under another name or is there  a company to reference?

Comment: it is submitted with vanitha3665@gmail.com this name.

Comment: this is the account Miracle Software Systems

Comment: thanks for the info - will check with the team to see what they have for that email and account.

Comment: Till now I am unable to access that service in IoT service. Can you help me to resolve this issue. Is there any other way to connect blockchain extension to IoT service

Comment: I had tried the gmail account you previously provided but did not receive a reply.  Is that your account/

Comment: I tried with the different account also.Is the only way to contact them to get the access to use that service.

Comment: I submitted the form with karikatla@miraclesoft.com

Comment: I didn't get any response from those people till now.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following API request to your browser and it will activate your extension: https://.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/api/v0002/blockchain/activate?code=1